# Issue with CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation on UIButton

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton, transformation, uitoolbar

I have a problem that I can't explain.

I have a viewController with a view.
This view contains a UIbutton and a toolbar.
Because the toolBar is a parameters bar, I don't want it to be present on my view all the time.
So I've decided to use a button to show it.

I'm using the interface builder to design my view.
The button will be in the top left corner, and the toolbar just above the view. (origin : 0  , -44)

I've linked my button to a IBAction function showing my toolbar :

```
- (IBAction)showOptions:(id)sender {
    if([parametersBar isHidden])
    {
        [parametersBar setHidden:NO];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             [parametersBar setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 44)];

                         }
         ];
    }
}
```

(parametersBar is set to be hidden in the viewDidLoad)

This works fine.

But here we are : my button is now hidden by the toolbar!!
So what about translate it too?

Impossible to make both of my elements translate of 44px!! I thought I was doing something wrong. But even by just making the button move move, the result of the translation is not the expected one.

```
- (IBAction)showOptions:(id)sender {
        if([parametersBar isHidden])
        {
            [parametersBar setHidden:NO];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                             animations:^{
                                 [parametersButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 44)];

                             }
             ];
        }
    }
```

I've put some NSLogs before and after the animation : they write the expected positions of my button but on my device screen, it is not at the right place.
And performing a translation at the two elements results that the toolbar doesn't go at the right place.

I'm using Autolayout in my .xib . Could it be the reason of these issues?
Does performing a transformation on the button which asks for this transformation has an influence?

(By the way, running the same code on a 3GS hasn't the same effect : the button jump, and makes the translation expected from where it is (44px above) to its original position)

Well, this problem is difficult to explain, but I hope to be clear.
If you need more precisions to understand, don't hesitate to ask me for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative to my problem.

Replacing the line :

```
[btShowParam setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -44)];
```

With :

```
[btShowParam setCenter:CGPointMake(btShowParam.center.x, btShowParam.center.y + 44)];
```

Makes the button animating well.

So finally, I have :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             [parametersBar setCenter:CGPointMake(parametersBar.center.x, parametersBar.center.y + 44)];
                             [btShowParam setCenter:CGPointMake(btShowParam.center.x, btShowParam.center.y + 44)];
                             [btShowParam setAlpha:1];
                         }
         ];
```

But I still wanting to know why setTransform: doesn't work on my UIButton, and why this function doesn't work on several items simultaneously.